# How to Call External WebService Using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, web-services

I Am New to JQuery, I Am Using a Webserice : http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit  ( It Converts Celsius To Fahrenheit ), i Am Calling This Web Service By Using JQuery, JQuery Code That i Written Is :

function CallWebService(){

```
$.ajax({

            url:'http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit',
            data:"{Celsius:2}",
            type:'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'jsonp',

     success: function(evt){             
         alert("Success");           
         },

         error: function (response) {                      
        alert("Failed");         
                    }
    });
```

}

Always It's Executing Error Function, I Donno What went wrong Here, Any Help will appreciable

- Thanks

Rajeev

Comment: I think the webservice is down,try using it's url directly on your browser window. Other than that, it seems the request is perfect

Comment: Thank you, Web Service is working Perfectly.. But when i tried to call it from JQuery it's giving error !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the parameters of the error response 
instead of

error: function (response) {..}

use

error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {...}

If that isn't informative you also can watch webtraffic with Charles, Fiddler etc. Server response should be informative.